# Comparing definitions of Continuity given in Real Analysis and Topology respectively

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

In Real Analysis we define continuity at a point, using the epsilon-delta formulation, however we encounter a more general definition of continuity in topology. Can we use modify that definition for "continuity at a point", of a map between two topological spaces.

Comment: I take it your problem is that you've had the definition of overall continuity of a map, but not continuity at a point.

Answer (score 3):

**Approach:**

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
\text{Continuity on } \Bbb R & \text{Topological space} \\ \hline
\text{Fix } \varepsilon  & \text{Fix a neighborhood }  V \text{of } f(x_0) \\
\hline
\text{exists } \delta   & \text{exists a neighborhood  }  U \text{of } x_0.\\
\hline 
|x-x_0|\le \delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(x_0)|\le \varepsilon    & f(U)\subseteq V \\
\hline
 \end{array}$$

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Let $f \colon X \to Y$ and $x \in X$. We say that $f$ is continuous at $x$ if given any neighbourhood $V$ of $f(x)$, there exists a neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ such that $f(U) \subseteq V$.